# Is it possible to control the audio input level of a microphone in the Operation System with Java?

Tags: java, audio, input

Can I use Java to control the audio input level of a microphone, so that I can change the audio input level in the Operation System. If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, that all entirely depends on 2 things -

1. The tools the microphone software has
2. The compatibility of the resulting edit to the type you are expecting (more on this in a bit...)

Let's start with some definitions first. The term you are looking for here is `Compression`

Compression is basically the pre formatting of your microphone, in this case, turning the input volume down all the way so that the loud sounds don't drown out your quiet ones. Compression is used by many musicians who are about to record a loud solo or plan to record a very quiet ambience. This is what you will be using to solve your problem.

Now, we will need to know more about your microphone before I can help you anymore on this point. Please comment in the comment section of this answer which microphone SPECIFICALLY you will be recording from. I will edit my answer as you give more info.

Comment: I'm not searching for a solution that fits for a single type of microphone. I'm searching for a solution to adjust the operation system volume of the audio input, no matter what kind of input.

Comment: Ahhhh, that's a different problem entirely. Well, unfortunately, not that's not possible, but each and every microphone has their own settings and functionality, it would be virtually impossible to create the basic code to do that. However, the last thing that I think could help is on Windows, there's an option to limit the audio input for generic microphones (Note that this does not work for all) through some of windows settings, would you want to do that instead?

Comment: Furthermore, please go into more detail about how you want to use this input, maybe we can solve this problem through other means